# GAE Python request.get arguments

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I need to be able to check to see if the link has any arguments being posted or not.

example:

www.hello.com/task
www.hello.com/task?link=thislinke

How should i check if there's arguments for "link" or not?

I tried this but didn't work:

```
if len(self.request.get_all()) > 0:
```

This is what i do when there is a link argument

```
link = (self.request.GET['link']).encode('ascii','ignore')
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method `self.request.get` returns an empty string for absent parameters, so just check if its result is empty.

```
link = self.request.get('link')
if link:
    # do some work with link
else:
    # there is no 'link' argument
```

Comment: just do "if link" more pythonic in this case I think ;)

Answer (score 2):

http://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/request.html

```
request = Request.blank('/test?check=a&check=b&name=Bob')

# The whole MultiDict:
# GET([('check', 'a'), ('check', 'b'), ('name', 'Bob')])
get_values = request.GET

# The last value for a key: 'b'
check_value = request.GET['check']

# All values for a key: ['a', 'b']
check_values = request.GET.getall('check')

# An iterable with alll items in the MultiDict:
# [('check', 'a'), ('check', 'b'), ('name', 'Bob')]
request.GET.items()
```